# Configure IIS to show contents of a long URL at a new short host name URL

Tags: redirects, iis

I've been asked to sort out short URLs for some of our internal domains.

So something like `http://2D-DEV1` to point at `http://my-server-name/APP_NAME/somemorestuff/thing.aspx`

The DNS for `2D-DEV1` points to the same IP address as `my-server-name`.
In IIS I've set up URL Rewrite so that it sends things off to the long URL when you input the short one.

Bu the issue is that I want it to keep displaying the short URL rather than switching to the long one.

My web.config file has something like the following in it

```
<rules>
    <rule name="2d-dev1" enabled="false" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="http://my-server-name/APP_NAME/somemorestuff/thing.aspx" appendQueryString="true" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^2d-dev1$" />
        </conditions>
    </rule>
</rules>
```

I've been trawling websites and youtube videos, but so far everything is concentrating on getting rid of the www or forcing https. Nothing details how to force a domain name to stay.
I did find one site that just said that you needed to use Application Request Routing, but I can't figure that out either.

Whoever set up this server has got one default website and three applications running under it. I need to be able to use a short URL to point to an individual application.

This is not my forte as I've not really used IIS before.

Comment: I've read this a couple of times now, and it's been several years since I worked in IIS.  But, it sounds like all you need to do is change your web root for each "host".  I.e., mapping the root of 2d-dev1 to my-server...  What am I missing?